# generate the right url in ajaxlink yii

Tags: php, ajax, url, yii

I have a problem resolving the url address in ajalink in Yii

the normal link works fine

```
<?php echo CHtml::link("Comments ({$data->commentCount})",$data->url.'#comments'); ?> |
```

it output is

/blog/index.php/post/2/A+Test+Post

but when I use $data->url in my ajaxlink  the '+' signs are replaced by spaces

then I use

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Test request',          
            array(str_replace("+", "", $data->url).'#comments'),
...
```

but I got the error

Unable to resolve the request "**blog/index.php/post/2/ATestPost**".

If I manually type the url  by prefixing with

```
http://localhost/
```

it works

```
http://localhost/blog/index.php/post/2/ATestPost
```

works.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want full URL, then you can use

```
Yii::app()->request->hostInfo . $data->url
```

Comment: Thank you @kumar_v.    I got the complete url  but still the error message.   I dont understand why ?   the error is  nable to resolve the request "http://localhost/blog/index.php/post/2/ATestPost".   but if I type http://localhost/blog/index.php/post/2/ATestPost  it works.  Isn't it related with urlmanager ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem  by transforming the address.

```
<?php $url_extract =substr($data->url, strpos($data->url, Yii::app()->controller->id)); ?>
<?php $url_replace = str_replace("+", "", $url_extract); ?>
```

and then in the ajaxLink, I use the^$url_replace

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Test request',             
            array($url_replace),
```

...

I dont know yet if it is the best solution.

Thank you for your help